# On drag an drop new element replace existing element and put old element back in list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6, drag-and-drop

I am using HTML drag and drop features. I am able to successfully drag and drop my elements from the list. But I want to be able to put back an element in the list and if I drag and drop a second element, the first one should be automatically put back.

As of now with my code that is not happening. When I drag a second element to replace the first one, it replaces the element fine but the first one is lost. Is there a way for me to put the first element back on the list?

My code:

```js
$('#drag1, #drag2, #drag3').on('dragstart', function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', e.target.id);
});

$('#div1').on('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    $('#div1').html($(`#${data}`));
});

$('#div1').on('dragover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  

<br />
<div id="div1" class='ml-2'></div>
<br />
<ul class='list-group d-inline-block ml-2'>
  <li id="drag1" class='list-group-item py-1' draggable='true'>one</li>
  <li id="drag2" class='list-group-item py-1' draggable='true'>two</li>
  <li id="drag3" class='list-group-item py-1' draggable='true'>three</li>
</ul>
```

As you can attest, if I first drag, `one` from the list to the div. I am not able to drag it back to put it back on the list. If I drag another element from the list, say `three`. I am able to replace `one` on the list with `three` but the `one` is lost. Is there a way to put it back on the list in being replaced?

Link to fiddle: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nb_nb_nb/oag1nf95/)

Comment: Create a jsfiddle please.

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS, I have just added it to the description above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the current item in the drop area (I've changed the id to `#target`), and it to the `#list`, and sort the items:

```js
$('#list').on('dragstart', 'li', function(e) {
  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', e.target.id);
});

var $target = $('#target');
var $list = $('#list');

$target.on('drop', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  $list.append($target.html());
  $target.html($(`#${data}`));
  /* ignore this block if you don't care about the order */
  $list.append(
    $list
      .children('li')
      .toArray()
      .sort((a, b) => +a.dataset.order - +b.dataset.order)
  );
  /*******************************************************/
});

$target.on('dragover', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#target {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<br />
<div id="target" class='ml-2'></div>
<br />
<ul id="list" class='list-group d-inline-block ml-2'>
  <li id="drag1" class='list-group-item py-1' draggable='true' data-order="1">one</li>
  <li id="drag2" class='list-group-item py-1' draggable='true' data-order="2">two</li>
  <li id="drag3" class='list-group-item py-1' draggable='true' data-order="3">three</li>
</ul>
```