# Not able to drop element when creating dynamic divs to drag and drop element in

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6, drag-and-drop

Following up on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67026470/on-drag-an-drop-new-element-replace-existing-element-and-put-old-element-back-in/67026713#67026713). It works perfectly. But when I dynamically create the divs where the li element is dropped in, I am not able to drop the element in it.

I am using the basic HTML drag and drop feature. Why is the `on drop` working with dynamically created div?

Here is my code:

```js
    ['harry', 'hermione', 'ron', 'ginny', 'luna'].forEach(met => {
        $(`#char`).append(`
            <div class="form-check py-1">
            <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input pickTarget" name='checkTarget' value="${met}">${met}
            </label>
            </div>
            `);
    });

    $('.pickTarget').click(function() {
        let unselected = $('.pickTarget:checked').length >= 3;
        $('.pickTarget').not(":checked").attr("disabled", unselected);
    });

    $('.pickTarget').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $(this).parent().append(`<div style='border: 1px solid red' class='float-right ml-3 text-muted target' id='drop_${this.value}'>Drag Number</div>`);
        else $(`#drop_${this.value}`).remove();
    });

    $('#list').on('dragstart', 'li', function(e) { e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', e.target.id); });

    var $target = $('.target');
    var $list = $('#list');

    $target.on('drop', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let data = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text');
        $list.append($(this).html());
        $(this).html($(`#${data}`));
    });

    $target.on('dragover', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<br />
<div id='char' class='w-50 float-left h-50 overflow-auto ml-5'><b>Characters</b> (select 3)</div>

<br />
<ul id="list" class='list-group d-inline-block ml-2'>
    <li id="drag1" class='list-group-item py-1' draggable='true' data-order="1">one</li>
    <li id="drag2" class='list-group-item py-1' draggable='true' data-order="2">two</li>
    <li id="drag3" class='list-group-item py-1' draggable='true' data-order="3">three</li>
</ul>
```

In my code, once you click on the checkbox next to a Harry Potter character, it creates a div. After selecting the 3 divs (only 3 allowed), divs are created next to the check box. I want to drag each of the `one, two & three` to each of the divs. Why is it not working?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nb_nb_nb/ubLa3fx0/1/) for my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target divs are dynamically created so you need to bind that with static elements which are already present inside your dom . So , just use  `$("#char").on('drop', '.target',..` and same for dragover event .

Also, in your code when user uncheck the checkbox and if there are any `li` item inside `target` div they are also get removed . Instead you check if the target div has any class with name `list-group-item` if yes then just clone that element and then append same to your `list` and finally remove whole div .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
['harry', 'hermione', 'ron', 'ginny', 'luna'].forEach(met => {
  $(`#char`).append(`
            <div class="form-check py-1">
            <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input pickTarget" name='checkTarget' value="${met}">${met}
            </label>
            </div>
            `);
});

$('.pickTarget').click(function() {
  let unselected = $('.pickTarget:checked').length >= 3;
  $('.pickTarget').not(":checked").attr("disabled", unselected);
});

$('.pickTarget').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent().append(`<div style='border: 1px solid red' class='float-right ml-3 text-muted target' id='drop_${this.value}'><span class='${this.value}'>Drag Number</span></div>`);
  } else {
    //check if the div has li item inside it 
    if ($(`#drop_${this.value}`).find(".list-group-item").length > 0) {
      var cloned = $(`#drop_${this.value}`).find(".list-group-item").clone() //yes clone it
      $("#list ." + this.value).remove(); //remove Drag Number span
      $("#list").append($(cloned)) //append li again in list
    }
    $(`#drop_${this.value}`).remove(); //finally remove div
    //you can write code for sorting lis ..here 
  }
});

$('#list').on('dragstart', 'li', function(e) {
  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', e.target.id);
});
var $list = $('#list');
//change this
$("#char").on('drop', '.target', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  $list.append($(this).html());
  $(this).html($(`#${data}`));
});
//change this
$("#char").on('dragover', '.target', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<br />
<div id='char' class='w-50 float-left h-50 overflow-auto ml-5'><b>Characters</b> (select 3)</div>
<br />
<ul id="list" class='list-group d-inline-block ml-2'>
  <li id="drag1" class='list-group-item py-1' draggable='true' data-order="1">one</li>
  <li id="drag2" class='list-group-item py-1' draggable='true' data-order="2">two</li>
  <li id="drag3" class='list-group-item py-1' draggable='true' data-order="3">three</li>
</ul>
```